# Allow onclick event on TR element but prevent the event in the checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, jsx

How can I allow onClick event on TR element but prevent the event in the checkbox? 
The checkboxes are children of TDs of TRs in table.

What I did in this problem is adding onClick on all TDs but not in the TDs of the checkbox.

Is there a better approach for this problem?

```
<tr key={item._id} id={item._id} className={(item.status == "unread")? "unread":""}>
    <td className="inbox-small-cells">
        <input type="checkbox" className="mail-checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td className="view-message  dont-show" onClick={this.viewMsg.bind(this,item.sender)}>{item.sender} {(item.category.length > 0)? 
                        <span className="label label-info pull-right">{item.category}</span>:""}</td>
    <td className="view-message " onClick={this.viewMsg.bind(this,item.sender)}>{item.subject.trunc(40)}</td>
    <td className="view-message  inbox-small-cells" onClick={this.viewMsg.bind(this,item.sender)}>{(item.attachments.length > 0) ? <i className="fa fa-paperclip"></i> : ""}</td>
    <td className="view-message  text-right" onClick={this.viewMsg.bind(this,item.sender)}>{item.createdAt}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Where is your code? Come with code please

Comment: little code snippet please..

Comment: if you are calling js function onClick you can think of removing this function on click of checkbox

Comment: If propagation can't be disabled, you could look at the nodeName: `event.target.nodeName === 'TR'`

Comment: `className="` what type of attribute is this from?

Comment: It is from JSX 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like everyone already stated [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation). We can also use CSS property `pointer-events:none` or attribute `disabled:true`. The following Snippet has 2 working examples using [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) and [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

**SNIPPET**

```js
// Option #1
$('.mail-checkbox1').css('pointer-events', 'none');


// Option #2
$('.mail-checkbox2').attr('disabled', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="inbox-small-cells">
    <label>Control #0 (Normal test case)</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox0">
    <br/>

    <label>Option #1 (pointer-events:none)</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox1">
    <br/>


    <label>Option #2 (disabled: true)</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox2">
    <br/>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.stopPropagation()` call on tds/checkboxes to propagate the event to its parents in the dom tree.

change to this:

```
<tr key={item._id} id={item._id} onClick={this.viewMsg.bind(this,item.sender)} className={(item.status == "unread")? "unread":""}>
    <td className="inbox-small-cells" onClick={this.stopEventProp(event)}>
        <input type="checkbox" className="mail-checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td className="view-message  dont-show">{item.sender} {(item.category.length > 0)? 
                        <span className="label label-info pull-right">{item.category}</span>:""}</td>
    <td className="view-message ">{item.subject.trunc(40)}</td>
    <td className="view-message  inbox-small-cells">{(item.attachments.length > 0) ? <i className="fa fa-paperclip"></i> : ""}</td>
    <td className="view-message  text-right">{item.createdAt}</td>
</tr>
```

Now you have to put this method in your class:

```
stopEventProp(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: can you provide an example how to use this?

Comment: @JohnArellano better to put the code you have tried instead. That would help us to provide you a better solution.

Comment: _this3.stopEventProp is not a function. This is the result.

Comment: Sorry. I put the stopEventProp funcion but still not working.

Comment: and where "event" coming from?

Comment: Sorry I have No idea about jsx.

Comment: It is ok. I think the problem is about the "event". Where it come from?